# Symmetry of functions on $S^2$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, curves-and-surfaces, surfaces

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $S^2$ and suppose there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for every $\mathcal{R} \in SO(3)$ the area of every connected component of $\{f(x)\geq f(\mathcal{R}x)\}$ is at least $C$ ($f(\mathcal{R}x)$ is a rotation of $f$ on $S^2$). Does there exist  $I\neq\mathcal{R}_0 \in SO(3)$ such that $f(x)=f(\mathcal{R}_0x)$ on an open subset of $S^2$?

Comment: Yes, I revised the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that any eigen-function satisfies your condition for some $C>0$.
It remains to find a non-symmetric one. Take for example 
$$f(x,y,z)=10\cdot x^3+y^3+\tfrac1{10}\cdot z^3.$$

Comment: Thanks Anton. Is it easy to see why such C exists for your example?

Comment: @MathStudent assume it does not, then passing to the limit, we get a point $x_0\in\mathbb{S}^2$ such that $f(x_0)=(f\circ\mathcal{R})(x_0)$, $d_{x_0}f=d_{x_0}(f\circ\mathcal{R})$ and  $\mathrm{Hess}_{x_0}f\le\mathrm{Hess}_{x_0}f \circ\mathcal{R}$, which is impossible; at least for the given $f$ (I might be wrong for general eigen-function).